# Xpages preview in browser vs preview in client

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, browser, client, xpages

I have a custom.css file where I custom my css and it looks different in the browser than in the client, why? Is there a way to add something to my css to look the same?

here is my css file:

```
    .panel-heading {
    font-size: 20px;
    }

    .navbar-right{
    margin-top:-50px;   
    text-align:center;
}

    .center.navbar .nav{
    float:none;
    vertical-align: top;
    }

.center .navbar-inner {
    text-align:center;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

I am using bootstrap theme amelia to create a nice look of the application.

Thank you,

Florin

Comment: what do you mean preview in browser vs client?

Comment: How do you bind the CSS resource to your application?

Comment: in XPages: add stylesheet to page.

Answer (score 0):

Notes client uses a version of XULRunner, the core of Firefox. But it doesn't correspond to the latest Firefox. References to resources outside the NSF work slightly differently, because the URL includes a /xsp element.

But I don't think that's the problem here. It's hard to tell without knowing what's not looking the same. In order to work that out, I would recommend adding the Firebug Lite control from the Extension Library to your layout custom control, so it's available on all pages. You'll then be able to use the Firebug-style panel to check the CSS and see what is and isn't being used.

Comment: In the browser it looks as I want, but in the client it doesn't. 1st it put's that bullet of the ul tag and 2nd it is not aligned correctly...

Comment: I'm not an expert on CSS, but Firebug Lite should help you identify what's being applied in the client.